# Change profile.do while starting Stata in batch mode

Tags: command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, stata

Is it possible to start Stata with a different `profile.do` file? Is there a command line option to set this?

For example, I have a `profile.do` for productive work and I want to use another `profile.do` to test some things or to initialize some other things.

I am not really a Stata user/developer, but I created a Java based add-in which needs to be initialized first. To have the switch to change the `profile.do` on start-up would help to setup a development environment which initializes the unfinished add-ins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, one cannot supply the file name as an argument.

Nevertheless, suppose you have a number of `profile.do` files saved on your computer:

```
profile1.do
profile2.do
profile3.do
```

Instead of copying the relevant commands from these files in the main `do` file, the best way to accomplish what you want is to simply use the `include` command in your
main `do` file. This will allow you to run your preferences as required and in whichever
`profile.do` file these are stored.

A toy example of the `main.do` file would then be the following:

```
include profile2.do
sysuse auto, clear
regress price mpg weight
```

As the help file of `include` points out, the advantage of this approach is that:

> *"...any local macros (changed settings, etc.) created by executing the file are
>   not dropped or reset when execution of the file concludes..."*

In this way, you can run in a clean and flexible manner different `do` files with
difference preference files, all in batch mode:

```
stata -b do main
```

Naturally typing `help include` will provide more information.